# How can I trigger a button which is not in a Composite which has focus, using a mnemonic keybinding (Alt + ?) in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have a following Composite hierarchy in my RCP/SWT application:

- a Form with two children in the Body:
  -- on the top, a Composite with data 
  -- on the bottom, a bar with buttons (Save, Print, etc.)

The buttons have mnemonics defined, but thy are not triggered by Alt+S, Alt+P, etc. I'm assuming the problem is that the focus is on the top Composite, and not on the Composite with the buttons, however I couldn't find any description on how the mnemonics work exactly...

Is my assumption correct? If yes, how can I "redirect" a key press from one Composite to the other?

I tried the following, but the listener is never entered (editorParent and buttonBar are the two Composites mentioned in the hierarchy above):

```
editorParent.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            Event event = new Event();
            event.keyCode = e.keyCode;
            event.type = SWT.KeyUp;
            buttonBar.getComposite().getDisplay().post(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            Event event = new Event();
            event.keyCode = e.keyCode;
            event.type = SWT.KeyDown;
            buttonBar.getComposite().getDisplay().post(event);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: 
The mnemonics are defined by setting the text of th buttons to &Save, &Print, etc. I know they work, because when I click on one of the buttons with the mouse, say on the Save button, then I can use Alt+P to print and it works until I go back to editing the data.

Comment: Can you show us the code for how you are defining the mnemonics, just to verify it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an editor or view to create form. It have some already defined methods such as `doSave()`
which works on ctrl+s .
you can place your code inside it to save or call an action to save data.

If you want your own shortcuts to work in eclipse workbench. Then create a command in eclipse plugin.